# Como usar 2 formularios uno get y otro post en una sola pagina

Tags: php, mysql

Lo que tengo son 2 formularios en un sola pagina el problema es que tengo uno que consulta la BD y en otro los datos de la base se escriben en los campos y tengo ese formulario para actualizar los datos obviamento con UPDATE, eso si funciona lo que no es que cuando le presiono al boton del segundo formulario no sirve y no quiere actualizar, alguien que me pueda ayudar

```
if(isset($_GET['submit'])) {

$Nombre=$_GET['campo-dato'];
$Lista=$_GET['campo-lista'];

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysqli_select_db($link, "gobbc");

$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM tbarchivos WHERE $Lista LIKE '%" . $Nombre . "%'");
$extraido= mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$codigo=$extraido['Codigo'];   

$campo1=$extraido['Nombre'];        
$campo2=$extraido['RFC'];      
$campo3=$extraido['Departamento'];       
$campo4=$extraido['Puesto'];       
$campo5=$extraido['Servicios'];      
(...)
$campo95=$extraido['Sist_NomEsp_cont'];
$campo96=$extraido['Sist_UABC_usu'];
$campo97=$extraido['Sist_UABC_cont'];
$campo98=$extraido['Sist_DIGISIBI_usu'];    
$campo99=$extraido['Sist_DIGISIBI_cont'];  

}
elseif (isset($_POST['Actualizar'])) {

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysqli_select_db($link, "gobbc");

$Codigo=$_POST['Codigo']; 

$campo1=$_POST['campo-nombre'];        
$campo2=$_POST['campo-rfc'];      
$campo3=$_POST['campo-departamento'];       
$campo4=$_POST['campo-puesto'];       
$campo5=$_POST['campo-serv'];      
(...)
$campo96=$_POST['campo-UsuUABC'];
$campo97=$_POST['campo-contraUABC'];
$campo98=$_POST['campo-UsuDIGI'];    
$campo99=$_POST['campo-contraDIGI'];

mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE tbarchivos SET Nombre='$campo1', RFC='$campo2', Departamento='$campo3', Puesto='$campo4', Servicios='$campo5', (...) Sist_UABC_usu='$campo96', Sist_UABC_cont='$campo97', Sist_DIGISIBI_usu='$campo98', Sist_DIGISIBI_cont='$campo99' WHERE Codigo='$Codigo'");
```

Ni asi funciona, no estoy seguro si asi debe ser

Answer (score 1):

La forma de hacerlo es:

```
<form .... caso #1... >
//debes cerrar el caso numero 1.
</form>

<form .... caso # 2... >
//debes cerrar el caso numero 2.
</form>
```

Entonces si haces `submit` en

> caso # 1

solo funcionara ese caso. E igual para
el numero2.

Lo que NO puedes hacer es que se hagan simultaneos.

Asimismo, cuando haces uno debes volver al inicio para hacer el segundo.

Y espero que esto te ayude te ayude. Si tienes más dudas, comenta y te asisto!